# PyQt Web Browser: Focus on the webpage without a mouse click

Tags: python, linux, webkit, embedded, pyqt

I am writing an application for an embedded device that has no mouse input.  The web browser is very very basic and does not have any buttons, address bar, file bar , etc.  For now, it simply just loads a web page.  This web page uses javascript to catch key press events for actions.

The problem I am having is that when the browser loads, the key presses are not caught.  I have tracked this problem down to what I believe is a focus problem.  When the browser loads, it does not have focus until a mouse click occurs on the application.  Since I do not have a mouse, that initial click cannot happen.

How can I make sure that the browser application gets focused correctly such that when I launch it from a terminal or script it will gain immediate focus and the key events can happen accordingly?

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.showFullScreen()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The **QWidget.setFocus()** did not work, assuming I used it correctly.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my laptop and the QWebView had focus already - once Google had loaded I could type and my text appeared in the text box.

If it is a focus problem then as QWebView inherits QWidget you can call its [setFocus()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#setFocus) method. Here is your code with an extra line calling the QWebView's setFocus method once a page has loaded:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.loadFinished.connect(web.setFocus)
web.showFullScreen()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus on the main frame:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebView()
    frame = web.page().mainFrame()
    frame.setFocus()
    web.showFullScreen()
    web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```